# confusion regarding transfer function of feedback system?

Tags: control, control-system

As shown highlighted in attached photo,the sign in denominator of the transfer functions

Are these both signs correct?or one of them should be negative?If yes,which one should be negative??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both are correct ,when we calculate C(s)/D(s) we assume R(s) to zero but due to summing point it gives output -C(s).H(s) that's why  still +ve sign in denominator

Comment: Both are correct, you can easily calculate the transfer function using Mason's gain formula without even writing anything.

Comment: Both are correct. For the disturbance effect case, you can shift the negative sign connected to the output of \$H(s)\$ to output of \$G_1(s)\$ (i.e. the second summing junction) without changing the input to output relation ship (for that particular selection of input and output).

Comment: As soon as there is one (or three or five...) minus sign(s) within a closed-loop, we have negative fedback and - consequently - a plus sign in the denominator of the closed-loop transfer function.